# How to get player's score in v7.2.2

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

in v6.x to get score I was using

```
FB.API("/me/scores", HttpMethod.GET, LoadScoreCallback)
```

where `LoadScoreCallback` used `FBResult`. Since `FBResult` has been replaced by `IGraphResult` in 7.x, I am unable to get my score through it. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IGraphResult returned from an FB.API call to "/me/scores" has the scores data as you would expect in v7.x+

Here is example code for parsing the result (note: You should add error-handling):

```
void handleScoresResponse (IGraphResult result)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(result.RawResult);

    var dataList = result.ResultDictionary["data"] as List<object>;
    var dataDict = dataList[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;

    long score = (long)dataDict["score"];
    var user = dataDict["user"] as Dictionary<string, object>;

    string userName = user["name"] as string;
    string userID = user["id"] as string;

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(userName + ": " + score);
}
```

See:
[image: Facebook Unity SDK Sample usage of me/scores]

Comment: Oh, I see, you were using built in example scenes to get Log printed out. Also nice to see `result.RawResult`, as it prints out the whole structure. It's also interesting to see that it is not needed anymore to use `Json.Deserialize` calls in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, is it really score data storied in a `long` format instead of regular `int` ?

Comment: @chanfort the `long` format is due to the way the `Json` class deserializes, you can always cast it to an `int` discarding any MSBs.

Comment: I was wondering if I would keep it as `long` all the time, i.e. if I would like to save very large score, let say 16 significant digits, would it be working?

Comment: On Facebook's side it looks to be a unsigned 32bit int, you can test this yourself easily with the Graph API Explorer. Submitting 4294967295 the maxValue for uint works, but add +1 and it fails: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=me%2Fscores&version=v2.5&score=4294967295